# How to use stun library python to get TURN relay allocation from remote server

Tags: python, webrtc, stun, ice

I'm building an application on Python to test WebRTC connection to a server.
What I've managed to do it get to the point where I get the TURN server information from the WebRTC server, see below:

{'turnPort': 3478, 'turnTcpPort': 443, 'turnAddress': '10.13.xx.xx', 'turnUsername': 'expturncreds', 'turnPassword': 'abcd123'}
{'turnPort': 3478, 'turnTcpPort': 443, 'turnAddress': '10.12.xx.xy', 'turnUsername': 'expturncreds', 'turnPassword': 'abcd123'}

Now i want to tell the program to send Allocate requests to the server using the information above and the stun library. Will this be possible? If so any pointers?

Comment: Which stun library?  Also, are you trying to just test connectivity, or are you trying to build a client that will do ICE ?

Comment: Both actually, The client will use STUN to get relay allocation from the TURN server with the credentials then test the candidates provided by a remote party.

Comment: The stun library i'm using is the pystun (stun) library https://github.com/jtriley/pystun/blob/develop/stun/__init__.py